# Using a temp table between stored procedures in SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I currently have a main stored procedure calling many stored procedures:

```
Main --| 
     --|
       --| > Exec Pre-processing SP (create and populate #temp table)
     --|
       --| > Exec Actual update
     --|
       --| > Exec Post-Process (consume and drop #temp table)
```

The problem I'm currently having is that I need to grab the original values from the database, and the values being passed into the main stored procedure so that I can execute post processing to the update in the last step (stored procedure) being called.

I cannot change the stored procedure signatures or the main stored procedure.

When I try to execute this scenario, I get an invalid object in the post-processing stored procedure.

How can I pass my values from the first stored procedure to the last stored procedure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create the temp table higher up in the calling hierarchy than all the stored procs that consume it. Since you say you cannot alter `Main`, the only chance to do this would be to create a new outermost procedure that creates `#temp` and then calls `Main`.

You can then modify the pre- procedure to populate the already existing table. You shouldn't need to explicitly drop the table anywhere.

---

Alternatively, you could create a permanent table, and include a spid column that indicates which connection data was inserted from. You'd also ensure that any selects/deletes against this table again use the `@@SPID` value. I posted this as an answer to [Session-global temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218009/session-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/5220257#5220257)

Comment: I worked around my limitations using the ## global temp table and the @@SPID to get my values from the global temp table.

Answer (score 2):

If the `main` procedure is always run on a single thread and will never be called in parallel from multiple connections, you could declare your temporary table as a global temp table (`##temp` as opposed to `#temp`), assuming you are able to change the inner procedure.

This won't work if `main` is called from several connections at the same time.

Comment: main is called from the UI of the application and can be called in parallel.

Comment: @Alexandre - in which case this solution is no use to you. Sorry.